# File migration issues

Tags: files, drush, migrations, 10

Well - where to start?
I'm trying to migrate a medium-sized Drupal 7 site to Drupal 10. I am just going to concentrate on the migrations of files.

I'm confused by a few things. One is that I am by default generating a migration called d7_file which comes out of Drupal core and another called upgrade_d7_file which comes (I believe) from the migrate_upgrade modules when configuring the migration.  Likewise there  are 2 different file migrations for the private files. I do not understand why there are two of them. It appears the public path for d7_file comes out of the settings.php file (but seems to be wrong anyway) and the upgrade_d7_file path comes from setting the configuration with migrate-upgrade.

I also have had continual problems with the input file paths for the migrations. It appears that however I configure the paths (except for configuring the public file path as https://my.site, which works fine) I keep on ending up with broken paths and getting errors because the migration is looking for the files at something like http://wherethefileshould be, therefore failing because there is no way to read that with no host.  Can someone help me understand what I keep doing wrong?